# linux char device create failed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I wrote a demo device driver like this:

```c
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#define CDEV_NAME "mycdev"

struct my_char_dev {
    unsigned char *ptr;
    struct semaphore sem;
    struct cdev cdev;
};

struct my_char_dev *mycdev;

int my_char_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}

int my_char_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}

ssize_t my_char_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}

ssize_t my_char_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_ops)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}

struct file_operations my_char_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_char_open,
    .release = my_char_release,
    .read = my_char_read,
    .write = my_char_write,
};

static int __init my_char_init(void)
{
    mycdev = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_char_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!mycdev) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "alloc space for device failed\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    if (!alloc_chrdev_region(&mycdev->cdev.dev, 0, 1, CDEV_NAME))
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s alloc region success\n", CDEV_NAME);
    else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s alloc region failed\n", CDEV_NAME);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    cdev_init(&mycdev->cdev, &my_char_fops);
    if (!cdev_add(&mycdev->cdev, mycdev->cdev.dev, 1))
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s add device success\n", CDEV_NAME);
    else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s add device failed\n", CDEV_NAME);
        unregister_chrdev_region(mycdev->cdev.dev, 1);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void __exit my_char_exit(void)
{
    cdev_del(&mycdev->cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(mycdev->cdev.dev, 1);

    kfree(mycdev);

    printk(KERN_INFO "%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

module_init(my_char_init);
module_exit(my_char_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("xdd");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

I insert module into kernel, and I could find a `mycdev` when I cat `/proc/devices`, I also made a device node under `/dev/mycdev` successfully by `mknod`, but when I attempt to operate the `/dev/mycdev` I have created, I got `/dev/mycdev0: No such device or address`.

This is what dmesg like:

```bash
$ dmesg
[  235.845810] test: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  235.845836] test: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[  235.846238] mycdev alloc region success
[  235.846239] mycdev add device success
```

This is device in `proc/devices`:

```bash
$ cat /proc/devices | grep myc
239 mycdev
```

This is how I used mknod:

```bash
$ sudo mknod /dev/mycdev1 c 239 1
```

This is the device I created:

```bash
$ ls -l /dev/mycdev1
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 239, 1 Nov 14 00:57 /dev/mycdev1
```

I attempt to use `cat` to operate the file I created:

```bash
$ cat /dev/mycdev1
cat: /dev/mycdev1: No such device or address
```

When I removed kernel module use `rmmod`, The module removed successfully, but when I check `/proc/devices`, there is a `mycdev` still alive:

```bash
$ sudo rmmod mycdev_module
$ cat /proc/devices | grep myc
239 mycdev
```

I have no idea why this would happen.

I want to know why this process will fail. and what should I do to correct my program.

Comment: You have a lot of `printk()`:s here and there and you won't share the logs with us? If so secret, why to even bother asking? Also, it's unclear what you meant under _operate the /dev/mydev_...

Comment: It's so sorry, I have just added what I have been done on my OS(ubuntu20.04 server), and what result I got.

Comment: You passed the wrong minor device number to `mknod`. It  should have been `0`, not `1`.

Comment: As a general point, I suggest returning the actual error codes returned by `alloc_chrdev_region()` and `cdev_add()` instead of replacing them with `-ENOMEM`. Also, if either of those functions fail, the code should free the memory pointed to by `mycdev`.

Comment: `cdev_init()` zeros out the `struct cdev`, which loses the `dev` value that was stored by `alloc_chrdev_region()`. You could move the `cdev_init()` call to occur before the `alloc_chrdev_region()` call to stop that happening.

Comment: ... It would be better to store the `dev` value set by `alloc_chrdev_region()` in a different variable though, as that gives you more options on how to support more than one device - you could either use a single `struct cdev` for all devices, or use an individual, embedded `struct cdev` for each device.

Answer (score 0):

The base device number (`dev_t` value) of the allocated character device region is being stored in `mycdev->cdev.dev` by this call:

```c
    if (!alloc_chrdev_region(&mycdev->cdev.dev, 0, 1, CDEV_NAME))
```

After that, `mycdev->cdev.dev` will be set to 0 by this call:

```c
    cdev_init(&mycdev->cdev, &my_char_fops);
```

`mycdev->cdev.dev` is 0 in the following call to `cdev_add()`:

```c
    if (!cdev_add(&mycdev->cdev, mycdev->cdev.dev, 1))
```

That call will set `mycdev->cdev.dev` to the value of the second argument, which is already its current value, 0.

That somehow succeeds even though major device number 0 is reserved for "unnamed devices", but obviously it is not what was intended.

In the module exit function, and in the error clean-up code in the module int function, `mycdev->cdev.dev` is still 0 in the following calls to `unregister_chrdev_region()`:

```c
    unregister_chrdev_region(mycdev->cdev.dev, 1);
```

That explains why the character device region registered by `alloc_chrdev_region()` is still registered after the module exits.

The problem could be fixed by moving the call to `cdev_init()` before the call to `alloc_chrdev_region()`. However, I think it would be better to store the `dev_t` value in a separate variable to decouple the registration of a character device region from the manipulation of `struct cdev` values.

For example, this file-level variable could be used to store the base of the registered character device number region:

```c
static dev_t mycdev_devt_base;
```

Then change the `alloc_chrdev_region()` call to:

```c
    if (!alloc_chrdev_region(&mycdev_base_devt, 0, 1, CDEV_NAME))
```

And change the `cdev_add()` call to:

```c
    if (!cdev_add(&mycdev->cdev, mycdev_base_devt, 1))
```

And change both `unregister_chrdev()` calls (in the module init error clean-up code and in the module exit function) to:

```c
    unregister_chrdev_region(mycdev_base_devt, 1);
```

---

The error clean-up code in `my_char_init()` leaks memory if either of the calls to `alloc_chrdev_region()` or `cdev_add()` fail. The allocated memory pointed to by `mycdev` is never freed in those circumstances. The function also returns `-ENOMEM` in those circumstances, but it would be better to return the error number returned by the function that failed.

It is common practice to use `goto some_label;` to do the clean-up in the reverse order of allocation, something like this:

```c
static int __init my_char_init(void)
{
    int rc;

    mycdev = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_char_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!mycdev) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "alloc space for device failed\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    rc = alloc_chrdev_region(&mycdev_base_devt, 0, 1, CDEV_NAME);
    if (rc) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s alloc region failed - err %d\n", CDEV_NAME, rc);
        goto fail_alloc_chrdev_region;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s alloc region success, major=%u, base minor=%u\n",
           CDEV_NAME, MAJOR(mycdev_base_devt), MINOR(mycdev_base_devt));

    cdev_init(&mycdev->cdev, &my_char_fops);
    rc = cdev_add(&mycdev->cdev, mycdev_base_devt, 1);
    if (rc) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "%s add device failed - err %d\n", CDEV_NAME, rc);
        goto fail_cdev_add;
        return rc;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s add device success\n", CDEV_NAME);

    return 0;

    /* cdev_del(&mycdev->cdev); */
fail_cdev_add:

    unregister_chrdev_region(mycdev_base_devt, 1);
fail_alloc_chrdev_region:

    kfree(mycdev);
    return rc;
}
```

The above version of the function reports the base major and minor number of the allocated character device number region.  The major device number will be allocated dynamically; the minor device number will be 0, as set by the second argument of the call to `alloc_chrdev_region()`.

---

OP used the `mknod` command to create a character-special file, using the major device number reported in the `/proc/devices` file and the minor device number 1. Even if the driver module was working as intended, this file wouldn't correspond to a a registered character device because the driver module only reserved minor device number 0.

Comment: Can you enable syntax highlighting?